# Invalid file error

Tags: file-upload, attachments

I get the following error when trying to upload a PDF file to a SharePoint list.  File is less than 20MB. Have previously been able to upload these files.  Still able to upload some PDF files but not all. Not sure what is causing the error.

> Invalid file name.
>
> The file name you specified could not be used.  It may be the name of
>   an existing file or directory, or you may not have permission to
>   access the file

Comment: What is the file name? Have you tried renaming it before you try to upload it?

Comment: Look at ULS.log...this errors not full.

Comment: often occurs due to improperly deployed content type; did you reorganize or delete content types before this error has come up?

Comment: Filename is October 2018.pdf have tried changing this. Worked for previous month September 2018.

Comment: No changes have been made to content types

Comment: Not sure if some sort of update is causing this as still working ok in my Test environment